# how avoid time out in updateMany() mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongo-shell

I'm getting

MongoNetworkTimeoutError: connection 11 to *** timed out

when I try to run the following updateMany via _mongosh:

```
db.collection.updateMany(
  {
    "name":"test"
  },
  { 
    $set: 
    { 
      "name" : "TEST" 
    } 
  }
)
```

any suggestion on how to avoid time out?

Comment: how many records are you attempting to update?

Comment: MongoNetworkTimeoutError would imply the connection never fully established.

Comment: It's around 1.5m records